# How is this form built?

Tags: forms

I'm trying to figure out how a form like this is constructed/styled (CSS? Javascript?):

[image]
It can be found at the very bottom of http://www.masterdynamic.com/

I want to say it's made through some sort of Javascript library, but could be totally wrong. I tried inspecting with Chrome Dev Tools, but couldn't really get a clear idea. Not really sure where to start with styling something like this (or even what to search for, all efforts have brought me to normal forms).

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" 
 dir="auto" aria-label="Email  " title="" autocomplete="off">

form input[type=text] {
  width: 80%;
  color: #b1aca1;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  font-family: blenderthin,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 3rem;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```